# Android WebView openFileChooser not called

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webchromeclient

I can't get the `openFileChooser()` to work. I'm not on Android KitKat (as we know this method doesn't work anymore on 4.4). I tried a different solution but it didn't work too.

Here is the html:

```
 <a class="myClass" href="./gallery_files/gallery.html" title="" onclick="document.getElementById('upload_').click(); return false;">




<form class="avatar" action="myUrlIsHere" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="upload_" class="invisible upload" type="file" name="Avatar">
</form>
```

And here is my WebChromeClient class:

```
public class WebViewChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    private Activity activity;
    public Uri imageUri;

    public static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;

    private Context context;

    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public WebViewChromeClient(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.activity = mainActivity;
        this.context = mainActivity.getApplicationContext();
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
        Log.i("WebChromeClient", "openFileChooser() called.");
        // Update message
        mainActivity.setmUploadMessage(uploadMsg);

        if (uploadMsg == null) {
            Log.d("UPLOAD MESSAGE", "NULL");
        }

        try {
            File imageStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    "Audi");

            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }

            // Create camera captured image file path and name
            File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                    + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
            mainActivity.setmCapturedImageURI(mCapturedImageURI);
            Log.d("Line", "57");
            // Camera capture image intent
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
            mainActivity.setmCapturedImageURI(mCapturedImageURI);

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");

            // Create file chooser intent
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

            // Set camera intent to file chooser
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                    new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });

            // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity

            activity.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent,
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Exception:" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
        Log.i("WebChromeClient", "openFileChooser() called.");
        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
    }

    // openFileChooser for other Android versions
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
            String acceptType, String capture) {
        Log.i("WebChromeClient", "openFileChooser() called.");
        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
    }

    // The webPage has 2 filechoosers and will send a
    // console message informing what action to perform,android wml_siso init 
    // taking a photo or updating the file

    public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {

        //onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
        return true;
    }

    public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
         Log.d("androidruntime", "Show console messages, Used for debugging: "
         + message);
    }

}
```

You can see this line in the openFileChoser() method `Log.i("WebChromeClient", "openFileChooser() called.");` - there is nothing in the LogCat.

And the onActivityResult():

```
@Override 
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (requestCode == WebViewChromeClient.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "onActivityResult");

            if (null == uploadMsg) {
                Log.d("FileChooser Result", "58");
                return;
            }

            Log.d("MainActivity", "onActivityResult");
            Uri result = null;

            try {
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    result = null;
                } else {
                    result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent
                            .getData();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            uploadMsg.onReceiveValue(result);
            setmUploadMessage(null);
        }
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onActivityResult");
    }
```

Do you know where the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

Found a **SOLUTION** which works for me. It is adding one more rule in `produard-android.txt`:

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.webkit.WebChromeClient {
     public void openFileChooser(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like openFileChooser is not called in Kitkat 4.4. It was being called till android 4.3.
Although it works again on 4.4.3.

Comment: But there is some workaround. On HTC One running 4.4, I could upload Gmail attachment on it's default browser.